# Comma Operator in alignas

Tags: c++, expression, language-lawyer

This code compiled and ran fine (outputting 5) on Visual Studio 2019

```
#include <iostream>



int main(void) {

    alignas(2,3,9,8) int x=5;

    std::cout << x;


    return 0;
}
```

[in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) comma expressions are [explicitly disallowed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) in alignas. This compiled fine here. I changed the order and placed 9 or 3 at the end ([which is disallowed in alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)) and the program failed to compiling indicating the expression in the brackets is really being parsed as the comma operator. Is there a different meaning here or is this just VS allowing the programmer to get away with something they shouldn't.

Comment: I also tried it with a value smaller than 4 (the natural alignment for int is 4 so [this should result in an error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)) and the programmed still compiled and ran fine outputting 5

Comment: @KamilCuk I have not heard that. That is actually very interesting to know and would answer **a lot** of questions I had about VS

Comment: It's in [C11 6.6p10](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p10): `An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions`. So sometimes the behavior is technically strictly undefined, but compilers accept some forms as an extension.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question? Because in C++ [alignas( pack...)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) is a perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: @BigTemp C++ . The [article for alignas on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) was lacking in my opinion so I turned to C to see if it was similar enough that I could learn more. I was surprised by what I found when I tried to compile so I wanted to see if there really was a difference. Turns out it might be valid in both languages. I also just tried it on clang which failed so this might differ by implimentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*alignment-specifier* is required to enclose a *type-id* or a *constant-expression* ([[dcl.attr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr#nt:alignment-specifier)):

```
alignment-specifier:
    alignas ( type-id ...opt )
    alignas ( constant-expression ...opt )
```

And *constant-expression* is required to be a *conditional-expression* ([[expr.const]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#nt:constant-expression)):

```
constant-expression:
    conditional-expression
```

`2,3,9,8` is neither a *type-id* (obviously) nor a *constant-expression* (because comma has lower precedence than conditional operator `?:`).

Therefore, `alignas(2,3,9,8)` is a syntax error and should be diagnosed by a conforming compiler.